# Logstash: Simply output a matched field in stout

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I'm playing around with logstash and i simply want to stout a certain field (clientip) in the previously filtered log message.

My conf file looks like this:

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/var/log/nginx/some.log"
    }
}

filter {
        grok {
             match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}"}
        }
}
output {
        stdout {
            codec => plain
            format => "%{clientip}" 
    }
}
```

This gives me ERROR

> Unknown setting 'format' for stdout {:level=>:error}

When i output everything with codec json I see that this field is available...but I just need one field not every singe field from the pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nevermind.
format must be nested in plain:

```
output {
    stdout{
            codec => plain{
                    format => "%{clientip}"
            }
    }
}
```